# How to pass variable from form child to parent symfony?

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm facing a problem with Symfony3 forms.

I define a first form like this :

```
class MyForm1Type extends AbstractType {
      /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', MyForm2Type::class, [
                'startDate' => 6,
            ])
        ;
    }
}
```

The second form:

```
class MyForm2Type extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'startDate' => null,
            'attr' => [
                'startDate' => ?????,
            ],
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getParent()
    {
        return DateType::class;
    }

    /**
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'datePicker';
    }
```

I would get fieldOption value in configureOptions function and add it to attr array, is that possible ? I need this value in my form theme to instanciate datePicker with a dynamic startDate parameter like this:

```
$('.input-datepicker').datepicker({
     startDate: "-{{ attr.startDate }}y",
});
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is simple :D

we have just to add attr attribute in the first form, like this :

```
$builder
            ->add('name', MyForm2Type::class, [
                'attr' => [ startDate => 6 ],
            ])
        ;
```

Comment: The questions asks "how to pass data from parent to child" doesn't this just set it on parent? If not can you explain how to use this in child?